# Counting visits and more in a mysql, any better practice or third party software?

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, counter, visitor-pattern

Let's assume i have a website like quora where i want to count how many visitors saw a particular page/question...("This question was visited 345 times")

i know i could create a column where i store a value that  increases every user visits it. 
But what about using some external service...that maybe can more robust and reliable (filtering unique/pageviews etc..)

any suggestion?

(what about Google Analytics API?)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google analytics? Or any of the other analytics packages will give you lots of info. Or you could run your own and put it on a memcached layer to make it super fast.

Comment: interesting...i have to look into this 'memcached' thing

Comment: Memcached is just a memory layer. You'll have to periodically save the data to a DB otherwise you'll lose it. But it'll be faster than constantly running an increment on mysql for every hit on your page.

Comment: Wow, interesting tip!! i'll try to install Memcached, sounds very good!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do it manually. There are some ways to do it...

If  you dont want try http://www.tinycounter.com/create.php kai for each url add one registration with the some email... Though this is not efficient for many pages!

Answer (score -1):

[google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: right, but can i display the single value for each page? do i have to use the API to surface those stats?

Comment: you can see stats per page. no need to use api, you get a nice web interface with stats and graphics